# How can a div be on top of every thing else without moving it outside it's container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div A contained in a container div B. Some other elements may overlap the containing div B based on its stacking order / context and that's fine. I want div A to be on top when container div is in focus.

Also, div A is positioned absolute within div B. Div B is also positioned absolute. When I move div A outside the Div B I lose positioning.

Is it possible div A to show on top keeping it's position?

My fiddle is here. Div A is the yellow square. I want it to show on top without changing zindex of Div B (red colored)

```
<div class="master">
    <div>
        <span class="red">
            Red
            <span class="yellow">yellow</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="green">Green</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="blue">Blue</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.red,
.green,
.blue,
.yellow {
     position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    //opacity: 0.8;
}
.master {
    //opacity: 0.9;
    background: grey;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    top: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
.red {
    background: red;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.yellow {
    background: yellow;
    top: 10px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 11;
    //opacity: 1;
}
.green {
    background: green;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.blue {
    background: blue;
    top: 75px;
    left: 75px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ManaKultras/51hnd663/5/

Comment: This is really confusing. You're mixing your terms here. The example has divs 'red', 'yellow' etc, yet your description says `A` and `B`. Please be clear about *exactly* what you're trying to achieve

Comment: yellow over green

Comment: I would say it is a really bad design... It an element has to be on top, just pull it out

Comment: only apply z-index when needed, here only to yellow and it's fine https://jsfiddle.net/51hnd663/6/ (make it simple at first :) )

Comment: By the way, if no parent z-index is changing, all I could think of is `position: fixed;`

Comment: @Imran, Is it possible to move the yellow div to be on the same level of the red div? (siblings instead of child-elements) Or maybe remove the parent divs of each of the colored divs?

Answer (score 0):

by what i understood you want the yellow element (span although you called it div ) to be on top of every other element. 
To do this you need to remove the z-index from the red div.

```
.red {
  background: red;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;

}
```

here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/51hnd663/7/)

Comment: "I want it to show on top without changing zindex of Div B (red colored)" check the question again :)

Comment: Many thanks. Unfortunately I need zindex on container div. It could be on top of other divs / spans

Comment: That is impossible as z-index is always inherited from the parent (if it is set). To make sure that this element doesn't go on top of other elements or goes whatever you want you can use z-index in other elements.